# I want to add class in the container while dropping a div in the container

Tags: jquery, css, drag-and-drop

I am using "jquery.sortable.js" to create a drag and drop following is the code

**js**

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('.sortable').sortable();
        $('.handles').sortable({
            handle: 'span'
        });
        $('.connected').sortable({
            connectWith: '.connected'
        });
        $('.exclude').sortable({
            items: ':not(.disabled)'
        });
    });
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<ul class="connected list">
    <li>Customer</li>
    <li>orders</li>
    <li>inventory</li>
    <li>shipping</li>
</ul>
<ul class="connected list no2"></ul>
```

while drag and drop is working perfectly but i want to a class in the second "connected" box while dragging an item over it.

looking for this solution all over but unable to find it.

Answer (score 0):

Check jQuery UI documentation for droppable method used with sortable.

You can see the example [here](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#connect-lists-through-tabs).